# java.lang.ThreadLocal - How each Thread has its own, independently initialized copy of the variable?

Tags: java, thread-local

The javadoc about the class java.lang.ThreadLocal is making me confused. They are saying that each thread that access a thread-local variable has its own, independently initialized copy of the variable.
Here is an example (not a true life example) who proves that variable held in a thread-local variable could be shared by many threads:

```
package com.mohamad.test.threadlocal;

import java.util.List;

public class ThreadLocalExample {

    private static final ThreadLocal<List<Integer>> myThreadLocal = new ThreadLocal<List<Integer>>();

    public static List<Integer> get() {
        return (myThreadLocal.get());
    }

    public static void set(List<Integer> value) {
        myThreadLocal.set(value);
    }
}


package com.mohamad.test.threadlocal;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;


public class TestThreadLocal implements Runnable {

    private static List<Integer> MY_TEST_LIST = new ArrayList<Integer>(){
        /** The serialVersionUID */
        private static final long serialVersionUID = -2419885728976816054L;
        {add(1);}
    };


    /* (non-Javadoc)
     * @see java.lang.Runnable#run()
     */
    public void run() {
        ThreadLocalExample.set(MY_TEST_LIST);
        List<Integer> integers = ThreadLocalExample.get();
        integers.remove(0);
        System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + " finished successfully, The list's size is: "  + ThreadLocalExample.get().size() + "\n");
    }

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        TestThreadLocal thread1 = new TestThreadLocal();
        Thread t1 = new Thread(thread1);
        t1.start();
        TestThreadLocal thread2 = new TestThreadLocal();
        Thread t2 = new Thread(thread2);
        t2.start();
    }
}
```

If we run this exemple, a `java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException` will be thrown because of the `MY_TEST_LIST` that is shared by `thread1` and `thread2`. (And as we saw, when  thread1 and thread2 called the `set(MY_TEST_LIST)` method of `ThreadLocalExample`, that called the set method of the `ThreadLocal` variable, it didn't create an independent local copy of the `MY_TEST_LIST`)

If somebody has already asked this question, please give the link to the answer because i did't find anything interesting while making a research on google.

Regards,

Comment: A `ThreadLocal<T>` can be viewed as a `Map<Thread,T>` with some extra methods to control initialisation.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Everything is fine. Variable hold in `ThreadLocal` is local to the thread. In your case it is a *reference* that is local, not the list itself. Each thread has its own copy of the reference, but all these references point to the same location. In other words: each thread can keep a reference to a different `List` but in your case they all point to the same one.

If you want your example to work, each `ThreadLocal` should point to a different `ArrayList` (a copy):

```
myThreadLocal.set(new ArrayList<Integer>(value));
```

Having `ThreadLocal`s all pointing to the same object doesn't make much sense as in this case you only need a single, globally available reference.

Comment: why didn't they call these `List` something like `ListRef` I wonder... `new` is something you need to disambiguate, I mean in plain English. it arguably doesn't actually seems to conform the naming conventions Java otherwise keep, even if it's historical.

Answer (score 2):

You stored the same list reference inside two thread-local variables. That doesn't mean the ThreadLocal don't have a value per thread. Your test should start one thread which stores something into the thread-local, then start another thread that looks if the thread-local variable contains anything (and it won't).

That's exactly like if you had two Maps, and stored the same list in both maps. Obviously, if you modify the list stored in one map, the list stored in the other map will be modified, since it's the same list. But clearing one map doesn't clear the other map.

Answer (score 1):

ThreadLocal doesn't enforce each thread to have a different reference, it allow each thread to potentially have its own copy depending on how you set it.

Just like each object having its own field, you can still set that field in every object to the same value, or you can set the values to be different.

It may be worth reading the source for the java.lang.Threads class to see how ThreadLocal is actually implemented.

Comment: I totally agree with you! But i think that it's not very well explained in the javadoc. The developer has to read the source for the java.lang.ThreadLocal to know how does it work exactly.

Comment: If all you need to know is how to use it, but not how it works, what would you add to the javadoc?

Comment: @PeterLawrey I am not sure whether I should be using `ThreadLocal` in one of my SO question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37125694/initialize-socket-timeout-value-in-httpclient-and-then-use-it-with-resttemplate). Wanted to see if you can help out. I haven't got any response yet and I was confuse whether using `ThreadLocal` is the right option or there is any better way.